# onselectedindexchanged does not fire in Firefox and IE

Tags: asp.net, firefox

I have an application build on asp.net in which I am using Free text box control. The application is running fine in Chrome but in Firefox I am getting below error:

> TypeError: FTB_API.MainContent_popEditProj_txtEditdescription is undefined.

Below are the details where I am getting the error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
FTB_API['MainContent_popEditProj_txtEditdescription'].StoreHtml();FTB_API['MainContent_newtask_taskdescription'].StoreHtml();FTB_API['MainContent_pproj_description'].StoreHtml();
return true;
}
//]]>
</script>
```

The browser is generating this by itself. My aspx code is as follows:

```
<FTB:FreeTextBox ID="txtEditdescription" runat="server" EditorBorderColorDark="Gray"
EditorBorderColorLight="Gray" GutterBorderColorDark="Gray" GutterBorderColorLight="White"
Height="200px" ToolbarStyleConfiguration="OfficeXP" Width="950px" BackColor="Silver">
</FTB:FreeTextBox>
```

This is just one instance where I am using FTB control.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this attribute to your FTB:

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

So:

```
<FTB:FreeTextBox ID="txtEditdescription" runat="server" EditorBorderColorDark="Gray"
EditorBorderColorLight="Gray" GutterBorderColorDark="Gray" GutterBorderColorLight="White"
Height="200px" ToolbarStyleConfiguration="OfficeXP" Width="950px" BackColor="Silver" ClientIDMode="Static">
</FTB:FreeTextBox>
```

Comment: After adding ClientIDMode="Static" i m getting the following error: TypeError: FTB_API.txtEditdescription is undefined seems that it has just removed "MainContent_popEditProj_" from comtrol ID, the error is still there